# Object Declaration/Relationship in angular models

Tags: angular, typescript, models

is it possible to do something like this
I wanted to declare an object inside my model the first one i tried is

```
export class Employee{
    emp_id: number;
    emp_fname: string;
    emp_lname: string;
    emp_birth: string;
    emp_status: string;
    emp_photo: string;
    emp_department: string; 
    department: Array<object> = 
    [{
        dept_id: number;
        dept_name: string;
    }];
```

the second one was like this

```
import { Department } from "./department.model";

export class Employee{
  constructor(department: Department){};
    emp_id: number;
    emp_fname: string;
    emp_lname: string;
    emp_birth: string;
    emp_status: string;
    emp_photo: string;
    emp_department: string; 
    department: department;

}
```

both return errors in my terminal:
first one returns expects , but when i make it so it says that I should use eg:number as type not as value.

Then the second one returns an error

Cannot find name 'department'.

my department model

```
export class Department {
    dept_id: number;
    dept_name: string;
}
```

Comment: department is supposed to be an array of Departments?

Comment: is it wrong? I don't know what to do I wanted to declare an object within an object kind of model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export class Department {
    dept_id: number;
    dept_name: string;
    constructor(dept_id, dept_name){
        this.dept_id = dept_id;
        this.dept_name = dept_name;
    }
}

export class Employee{
    emp_id: number;
    emp_fname: string;
    emp_lname: string;
    emp_birth: string;
    emp_status: string;
    emp_photo: string;
    emp_department: string; 
    department: Department[] = [new Department(1, "dept_name1"), new Department(2, "dept_name2")];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.